# Receiving a static URL from blob in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

In my app, I am creating a blob which is correctly uploaded in the App Engine Dashboard. However, this created file needs to be send to the respective person via email. In order to do this I either need the file itself as an attachment or a static URL where this person can download it. I have trouble figuring out how to obtain a static URL from the blobkey.

This is the code to create a file, it's nothing special though:

```
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/csv')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write(dataset)
files.finalize(file_name)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)

new_url = blob_key.urlsafe()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serve the file, look at the [Blobstore Overview - Serving a Blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob).

If you want to send it as an attachment see the [Attachments Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments). You will need to [fetch the contents of the blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) and then attach it to the mail.

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

# blob_key = ...

# Instantiate a BlobReader for a given Blobstore value.
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)

# Read the entire value into memory. This may take a while depending
# on the size of the value and the size of the read buffer, and is not
# recommended for large values.
blob_contents = blob_reader.read()
```

Comment: ignore my (deleted) answer. This answer and it's link explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AppEngine Blobstore docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob), they do a good job of explaining how to retrieve and work with Blobstore entries. Here is the example from the docs.

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case is different, but I am serving static content from the blobstore by looking up the url path.  Here is the model and the get function.

```
class StaticContent(db.Model):
    body = db.BlobProperty()
    content_type = db.StringProperty()
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now=True)
    etag = aetycoon.DerivedProperty(lambda x: hashlib.sha1(x.body).hexdigest())

def get(path):  
    return StaticContent.get_by_key_name(path)
```

You can see my wepapp2 handler on [step1 tag of my master branch in my git hub repo](https://github.com/jwogrady/sprucepress/blob/step1/static.py)

For a detailed explanation, you might also check out [Nick Johnson's blog post on serving static content via a blogstore](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-1-Static-serving).